# Changing the url (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, get, request

I have developed my website
It uses keywords in the link but want to hide this from users

I am using this

```
$keyword = $_REQUEST['key_word'];
```

which is being linked by this

```
<li><a href="home.php?key_word=abstract">Abstract</a></li>
```

How do I get rid of this in the url which looks like this home.php?key_word=abstract, I want it to look like this: home.php

Also, I have used IndexIgnore * in my .htaccess file, but doesn't seem to do anything but go to the Error 404 page

Comment: EDIT: "home.php?key_word=abstract" is what its suppose to say in the post after the $_REQUEST statement including the a and href tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If keywords are present in URL you can store it in `$_SESSION` for example and redirect user to plain URL.

```
if ($_GET['key_word']) {
    $_SESSION['keywords'] = $_GET['key_word'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], true);
}

// read keywords from $_SESSION['keywords'] here
```

After that keywords will only be visible in pointing URL, after user enters the site keywords will be deleted from the URL but stored in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Oh wow, such a noob, I'm giving you rep dude, it works a treat :)

Comment: Oh I can't rep you, I need 15 to rep you dude, but I can swear it does work, thanks a lot

Comment: Change third line to: `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], true);` Should work now.

Comment: nope, that makes the server come up with domanname/domainname in the url bar

Comment: It works because I was doing something else in the script which was clashing with it, thanks dude again